# ASP.net Web form VS ASP.net AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, forms

I need to develop web application using ASP.net with C# to handle mysql database (viewing, adding, updating, and deleting).

usually I would use asp.net webform to develop this application with C# but now I'm considering to use AJAX but not sure if I should use it or not.

I have the option to do it.

should I switch to AJAX or no need and use only webform and why?

Please give me your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confused on what ASP.NET AJAX is, as it's not a competitive product to Webforms.  Instead you may want to look at ASP.NET Dynamic Data instead of Webforms if you're only looking at handling standard CRUD actions.  It will work for Entity Framework, which should be able to connect to MySQL.